# Return all rows when a condition is met for other columns [R]

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I wanted to ask this question:

> Which individuals are from planets and genders where there are *any* individuals that have blond hair and blue eyes?

I can do this easily enough in two steps.

1. create subset of individuals with blond hair *and* blue eyes
2. use the planets and genders present there to do another filter

If there a way that I can do this in one step using a dplyr-like approach?

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
any_blond_blue <- starwars %>%
  group_by(homeworld, gender) %>%
  filter(eye_color == "blue", hair_color == "blond")


starwars %>%
  filter(
    homeworld %in% any_blond_blue$homeworld,
    gender %in% any_blond_blue$gender
  )
#> # A tibble: 9 × 14
#>   name      height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender
#>   <chr>      <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 Luke Sky…    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu…
#> 2 C-3PO        167    75 <NA>       gold       yellow         112   none  mascu…
#> 3 Darth Va…    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu…
#> 4 Owen Lars    178   120 brown, gr… light      blue            52   male  mascu…
#> 5 R5-D4         97    32 <NA>       white, red red             NA   none  mascu…
#> 6 Biggs Da…    183    84 black      light      brown           24   male  mascu…
#> 7 Anakin S…    188    84 blond      fair       blue            41.9 male  mascu…
#> 8 Finis Va…    170    NA blond      fair       blue            91   male  mascu…
#> 9 Cliegg L…    183    NA brown      fair       blue            82   male  mascu…
#> # … with 5 more variables: homeworld <chr>, species <chr>, films <list>,
#> #   vehicles <list>, starships <list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `filter`ing to create a new dataset, do the `filter` within the `filter` itself i.e. subset the values of 'homeworld', 'gender' based on the logical expression (`eye_color == 'blue' & hair_color == 'blond'`), then use `%in%` to create the logical expression for 'homeworld' and 'gender' to be used in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>% 
  filter(homeworld %in% homeworld[eye_color == 'blue' & hair_color == 'blond'], 
   gender %in% gender[eye_color == 'blue' & hair_color == 'blond'])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 14
  name  height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender homeworld species films vehicles starships
  <chr>  <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   <lis> <list>   <list>   
1 Luke…    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [2]>
2 C-3PO    167    75 <NA>       gold       yellow         112   none  mascu… Tatooine  Droid   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
3 Dart…    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [1]>
4 Owen…    178   120 brown, gr… light      blue            52   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
5 R5-D4     97    32 <NA>       white, red red             NA   none  mascu… Tatooine  Droid   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
6 Bigg…    183    84 black      light      brown           24   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [1]>
7 Anak…    188    84 blond      fair       blue            41.9 male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [3]>
8 Fini…    170    NA blond      fair       blue            91   male  mascu… Coruscant Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
9 Clie…    183    NA brown      fair       blue            82   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
```

---

Or slightly more compact and general approach would be using `if_all/if_any` as it can be applied to multiple columns.  Here, we use `if_all` so that it returns TRUE only when both column conditions are TRUE

```
starwars %>%
   filter(if_all(c(homeworld, gender),
    ~ .x %in% .x[eye_color == 'blue' & hair_color == 'blond']))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 14
  name  height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender homeworld species films vehicles starships
  <chr>  <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   <lis> <list>   <list>   
1 Luke…    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [2]>
2 C-3PO    167    75 <NA>       gold       yellow         112   none  mascu… Tatooine  Droid   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
3 Dart…    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [1]>
4 Owen…    178   120 brown, gr… light      blue            52   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
5 R5-D4     97    32 <NA>       white, red red             NA   none  mascu… Tatooine  Droid   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
6 Bigg…    183    84 black      light      brown           24   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [1]>
7 Anak…    188    84 blond      fair       blue            41.9 male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [3]>
8 Fini…    170    NA blond      fair       blue            91   male  mascu… Coruscant Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
9 Clie…    183    NA brown      fair       blue            82   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>
```